# Wso2 IS 5.10.4 Error while updating Service Provider: Duplicate Key

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I try to switch an SP from Authentication Type: Basic,  to Federated Authentication: our azure idp, I receive the following gui popup error:

Error while updating Service Provider : Duplicate key [Lorg.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.Property;@7ba219e7

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see an error stack trace print on the terminal? If so please add the stack trace here.

Comment: Do you have a custom federated authentication connector for azure?

Answer (score 1):

The same issue is reported in [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/6048). The reason is due to having more than one authenticator registered with the same name.
If you have added custom authenticators please check whether the authenticator name is the same as the previously existing authenticator's name.
Another reason could be you may have added the same authenticator in different versions.